# Routing setup for OpenVPN server on Amazon EC2

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn, static-routes

Software developer here, trying to get his sysadmin-foo up and running by setting up an OpenVPN server on amazon EC2 to access all the internal resources there. Here's how I envision that on a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 Canonical AMI:

```
   Local network          /        EC2 Cloud, 10.*.*.*/255.0.0.0
  172.16.20.*/          ,'
     255.255.255.0     ,'                +-----------------+
                      .'                 |Amazon DNS server|
                      |                ,'|  172.16.0.23    |
 +---------------+   |               ,'  +-----------------+
 | Workstation   |   |             ,'
 |               XXX |   +-------,'------+
 | 172.16.20.1   |  XXXX | OpenVPN server|
 +------`.-------+   \  XX  10.23.45.67  `-.  +-------------+
          \          '.  +---------------+  `-. Second server
  +--------`.---+     |                       | 10.23.45.68 |
  |Local server |      \                      +-------------+
  | 172.16.20.2 |       \
  +-------------+        \
```

Clients can connect to the VPN (even on iPhone), but I'm having trouble to get a full overview of which subsystems i need to check.

Here are my goals for the setup:

- VPN clients should be able to access internal resources via the vpn, the rest of the internet should be routed via the local gateway
- VPN clients should be able to access all servers the OpenVPN server can access
- VPN clients should use the Amazon DNS server at `172.16.0.23` as their primary dns server, because that server resolves Amazon's generated hostnames to internal ip addresses (i.e. `ec2-45-67-8-9.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` would resolve to `10.23.45.67` when resolved by that server, but to `45.67.8.9` everywhere else)
- VPN clients should see each other

Here's how I configured `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` (just the interesting bits, i hope):

```
persist-tun
server 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0
push "route-gateway 172.16.10.1"
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"

push "route 172.16.0.23"
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.16.0.23"
```

However, I'm not sure which parts of these the openvpn server does for me:

- Do I need to configure iptables on the server ? If so, how ?
- Do I need to set routes on the server (besides the ones being pushed to the client) ? If so, which and how ?
- What other networking software am I missing that causes my clients not to connect successfully ?

Comment: Can you set `verb 5` on a client and add in the connection logs to your original post, along with the `route print` or `route -n` output of the client when it's connected?

Comment: Are the VPN clients located in your local network (172.16.20.0/24)? Do they access the OpenVPN server via their local gateway (172.16.20.1) or do they connect to the server's public IP? If they are not in your local network: Shall they have access to the local network or just to the systems at Amazon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable forwarding on the OpenVPN server in the kernel (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`) and you have to globally or selectively allow forwarding in the firewall (iptables), e.g.:

```
# there is probably already a rule allowing all established connections
# iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# the next rules for every OpenVPN interface (or once for the respective address block)
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -d 10.0.0.0/8  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -d 172.16.0.23 -j ACCEPT
# if the local network shall be accessible
# iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -d 172.16.20.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

You need not set routes on the server if just simple clients connect. If 172.16.20.1 connects as a gateway for the local network then you need a route for 172.16.20.0/24 but that is probably (and best) set in the OpenVPN config for 172.16.20.1.

**Edit 1**

If you cannot configure the routing on certain systems and their routing would not send the traffic back the right way then you need NAT (more precise: SNAT):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d $PROBLEM_HOST_IP \! -s $LOCAL_IP \
  -j SNAT --to-source $LOCAL_IP
```

with the variables set accordingly. Assuming you can set the correct routing for targets in 172.16.20.0/24 only then you can do this easier this way:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s $LOCAL_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 2 -d 172.16.20.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 3 -j SNAT --to-source $LOCAL_IP
```

Comment: Hauke: Your anwswer is fine for the one node you're connecting to. The question is how to expose the rest of the nodes in the non-VPC EC2 cluster. Those don't have a TUN devices and they don't have routes to the OpenVPN server.

Comment: @nirvdrum See edit

Comment: @nirvdrum yes, that's the point of the question. I've configured everything with SNAT now, but having routes back to the OpenVPN server on all other nodes is even better ;)